# how do i figure out the basis for a vector space based on [x]b and v?

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem in the picture below:

[image]

I think since the basis for $\Bbb R^2$, there is a $b_1$ and a $b_2$ for me to figure out. 
I wrote out the systems like this: 
$$
4x_1 + 4y_1 = 2\\
3x_2 + 3y_2 = 3 
$$
and then the second set is 
$$
6x_1+6y_1 = 4\\
6x_2 + 6y_2 = 5 
$$

however, isn't this system inconsistent ? 
$2(3x_2 + 3y_2) = 2(3)$ from the first pair is the same as $6x_2+6y_2 = 6$, but in the second pair, $6x_2+6y_2 = 6$ should equal $6x_2+6y_2 = 5$.

The same constants times the same variables shouldn't equal different numbers right?

If i am wrong, please please correct me. thank you very much in advance.

Comment: For future mathematical typesetting, see [this tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: got it. thank you for fixing up my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *do not need to find* the basis for which this is the basis change, nor even the matrix whose application expresses the coordinate change. All you need to know is that basis change is always linear; then writing $\binom67$ as linear combination of $\binom23$ and $\binom45$ (as suggested by Omnomnomnom),take the same linear combination of their given images. More or less by inspection you can see that $\binom67=\binom45+(\binom45-\binom23)=2\binom45-\binom23$. So your answer is $2\binom66-\binom43$.

This computation in itself does not show that this linear map can be interpreted as a coordinate change at all for some basis. For that it is necessary (and sufficient) that the linear map be invertible; this can be seen to be the case here since the images $\binom43$ and $\binom66$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\c & d \\\end{pmatrix}$ $\begin{pmatrix}2\\ 3 \\\end{pmatrix}$ $=$ $\begin{pmatrix}4\\ 3 \\\end{pmatrix}$ $\implies 2a+3b=4,2c+3d=3$

$\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\c & d \\\end{pmatrix}$ $\begin{pmatrix}4\\ 5 \\\end{pmatrix}$ $=$ $\begin{pmatrix}6\\ 6 \\\end{pmatrix}$ $\implies 4a+5b=6,4c+5d=6$

$2a+3b=4,4a+5b=6 \implies a=-1, b=2$

$2c+3d=3,4c+5d=6 \implies c=3/2, d=0$

$\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 2 \\3/2 & 0 \\\end{pmatrix}$ $\begin{pmatrix}6\\ 7 \\\end{pmatrix}$ $=$ $\begin{pmatrix}8\\ 9 \\\end{pmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong system of equations.  Setting $u = [2,3]^T$ and $v = [4,5]^T$, then you should be trying to solve
$$
au + bv = \pmatrix{6\\7}
$$
For $a,b \in \Bbb R$.